# ViewModel object type properties in a collection are null on POST

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, devextreme

I have a View that renders inputs for custom field types. These are dynamic and configured by admins, each custom field can be an `int`, `DateTime`, `bool`, etc. Because of this I store `CustomField` values as `object` and back them by a `sql_variant` column type in SQL Server. The ViewModel for this View contains a collection of `CustomFields`:

```
public class EditDataViewModel
{
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
    public IList<CustomFieldViewModel> CustomFields { get; set; }
}

public class CustomFieldViewModel
{
    public Guid? CustomFieldId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomFieldTypeId { get; set; }
    public CustomFieldDataType DataType { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

These are rendered in my View using a for loop:

```
@{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (CustomFieldViewModel customField in Model.CustomFields)
    {
        @Html.Hidden($"CustomFields[{i}].CustomFieldId", customField.CustomFieldId)
        @Html.Hidden($"CustomFields[{i}].CustomFieldTypeId", customField.CustomFieldTypeId)
        @Html.Hidden($"CustomFields[{i}].DataType", customField.DataType)
        @Html.Hidden($"CustomFields[{i}].IsRequired", customField.IsRequired)
        @Html.Hidden($"CustomFields[{i}].DisplayName", customField.DisplayName)

        <div>
            <label>@customField.DisplayName</label>
            <div>
                @if (customField.DataType == CustomFieldDataType.Boolean)
                {
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().CheckBox()
                        .Name($"CustomFields[{i}].Value")
                        .Value(customField.Value != null ? (bool)customField.Value : false)
                    )
                }
                else if(customField.DataType == CustomFieldDataType.Date)
                {
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().DateBox()
                        .Name($"CustomFields[{i}].Value")
                        .Value((DateTime?)customField.Value)
                    )
                }
                // etc...
            </div>
        </div>

        i++;
    }
}
```

These do get posted back to the controller action:

[image: Request Body]

But the `Value` property of each `CustomField` is null, all other properties are populated correctly.

Edit: It appears to indeed be caused by binding to a property of type `object`. If I change the `Value` property in `CustomFieldViewModel` to `string` the property is set correctly in the controller action on Post.

Comment: What's the generated HTML for the checkbox or datetime picker box? I wonder if the name of those input boxes are generated correctly. I am not sure the logics inside your `DevExtreme()` and `Checkbox()`.

Comment: DevExtreme controls render a hidden `<input name="CustomFields[1].Value" type="hidden" value="">` element beneath their custom styled control. I left it out since it appears as though the encoded form data is being sent correctly.